# D3 and angularjs radio button intergation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I want to add few radio button like shown below in the legend of my this `http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/phsdeq4v/` D3 chart. So that when i click on any radio button it should call the function defined in the controller to fetch the data and then update the chart.

[image]

Also, this date should be customize-able, so that i can pass something like `config` while calling the d3Chart directive and according to my config, code should add appropriate number of radio buttons.

My problems:

1) get the value of the clicked radio button and pass the value of selected radio button & call a appropriate function in the controller?

Please anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I think , you can achieve this by using simple ngmodel directive upon any radio button . Check out https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ reference .Just research a little.

Comment: @katmanco: I tried but how to bind the function which is defined in the controller to the function in directive?

Comment: Hi again my friend , I just created a plnkr for you to check out how to bind a function to a directive that manipulates main scope's elements.That could help you .http://plnkr.co/edit/KzBWJzaFPzV8nMm9q64E?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link..[iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)

U can easily integrate with angulerjs using directives. Pls check below ex.

```
angular.module('test').directive('icheck', ['$timeout', '$parse',function($timeout, $parse) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
        return $timeout(function() {
            var value = $attrs['value'];
            $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue){
                $(element).iCheck('update');
            })

            $scope.$watch($attrs['ngDisabled'], function(newValue) {
                $(element).iCheck(newValue ? 'disable':'enable');
                $(element).iCheck('update');
            })

            return $(element).iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
            }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                    });
                }
                if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                    return $scope.$apply(function() {
                        return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

and use it in UI like..

```
<input type="checkbox" icheck name="Check" ng-model="checkConfig" ng-change="updateMode()"/>
```

Comment: Adding a new directive for radio button doesn't solve my problem. I have added few more details, please take a look. Thank You.